# Can many coroutines run asynchronously in one thread?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

As far as I know, I can run/start many coroutines in one thread using suspend functions, but can I run many coroutines asynchronously in one thread?

1.How to run them asynchronously and what is an example of it in code?

2.How to run them synchronously for me it is:

```
viewModelScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
launch {
firstSuspendMethod()
}

launch {
secondSuspendMethod()
}

}
```

For me this above code will run synchronously

3. How to run coroutines asynchronously using many threads?
4. Using Dispatchers.IO, Dispatchers.Main or Dispatchers.Default,
   does it run by default by many threads with many coroutines asynchronously. How does it work under the hood?

I've tried many approaches of my code and I was sure that it works asynchronously using Dispatchers.IO, because it does not wait for the result if I launch two different methods from different `launches`, but I start reading and everyone writes that using launch I run synchronously and with async asynchronously and now I am confused how really it works under the hood.

However, I got an answer from ChatGPT that what I think. That one coroutine block thread, but still we can start running many of them on one thread and just wait for the result and pause it then continue when it is done and when I want to use i.e. 64 thread I use `DIspatchers.IO`.

> Yes, potentially Dispatchers.IO can handle up to 64 asynchronous requests simultaneously. The Dispatchers.IO thread pool is configured by default to consist of 64 threads, allowing for the execution of multiple I/O operations simultaneously and increasing the efficiency of the application.
>
> However, the number of asynchronous requests that can be executed concurrently depends on many factors, such as the execution time of individual operations, the utilization of resources by the operating system, the number and type of other processes running on the system, and many other factors. Therefore, in practice, the number of asynchronous requests that can be executed simultaneously may be less than 64.
>
> It is also worth remembering that using a larger number of threads can lead to greater consumption of system resources such as memory and processor, which can affect the performance of the entire system. Therefore, it is necessary to adjust the number of threads according to the application's requirements and the characteristics of the system.

Comment: Please do not quote AI chatbot as a source.

Comment: Let's start with basics: what do you mean by "asynchronously" here? Asynchronously to what exactly? If you mean asynchronously to each other then yes, both `launch()` blocks run asynchronously, i.e. the second starts before the first end. But I assume you tried this first and if you think they work synchronously, then I guess you mean something else here. Also, `launch()` and `async()` are almost the same. The latter returns a result and the first doesn't.

Comment: GPT is wasting your time with answers that sound right but have subtle wrong information that will make you dangerous. Maybe someday it will be more sophisticated, but I think for learning programming it is more hindrance than help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this answer from GPT?

Comment: The answer below explains what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> potentially Dispatchers.IO can handle up to 64 asynchronous requests simultaneously

This is not really correct (nor should you rely on ChatGPT as a source).

A single thread can run many coroutines correctly.

If coroutine code blocks, it will stop any other coroutines from running on the physical thread.

`Dispatchers.IO` is specifically intended for use with operations that can block or otherwise take a long time, and can handle 64 of *those* happening concurrently.

This is implemented by allowing coroutines -- whenever they *suspend* -- to yield the thread to allow another coroutine to run.  Whenever the suspension resumes, the work gets put back in the queue to execute on the threads owned by the dispatcher.

The following, for example, will work just fine:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
  for (i in 1..1000000) {
    launch { println("foo") }
  }
}
```